# Bind touch gestures to gnome-terminal in i3

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal, i3

I'm trying to bind 2 touch gestures to go back and forth through the vim history in gnome terminal run against i3-wm, but have no luck:

```
  <application name="gnome-terminal">
    <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
      <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+o</action>
    </gesture>
    <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
      <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+i</action>
    </gesture>
  </application>
```

I can't figure out application name to match by. I've checked output for both `xwininfo` and `xprop`, but neither `Terminal`, `gnome-terminal` or even `gnome-terminal-server` is working.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, need to use `Gnome-terminal` name with capital 'G', as it's mentioned in `xprop` output:

```
...
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal-server", "Gnome-terminal"
...
```